# change captcha language dynamically

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I am having issues with the displayLang variable scope here. I would like to use the value inside the function but it keeps using the global one. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

I am calling this function from another script like changeCaptchaLang('FR').

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var displayLang = 'en';

function changeCaptchaLang(lang) {
    displayLang = lang.toLowerCase();
}

var RecaptchaOptions = {
    theme : 'clean',
    lang : displayLang,
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lang = 'FR';

lang = changeCaptchaLang(lang);
alert(lang + " " + RecaptchaOptions['lang']); // result: "fr fr"
</script>
```

File 2:

```
var displayLang = 'EN';

var RecaptchaOptions = {
    theme : 'clean',
    lang : displayLang,
}

function changeCaptchaLang(lang)
{
    displayLang = lang.toLowerCase();
    RecaptchaOptions['lang'] = displayLang;
    return displayLang;
}
```

If I'm not mistaken, displayLang in that function has new value only within function, but outside of it it's still the same old value.

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: This will work but my problem is that I am calling this function from another script by passing a language variable based on the page language. ie. changeCaptchaLang(pageLanguage) or something. If I pass the fr as a language here then my passed language gets ignored as it is going to default it to french.

Comment: @NepCoder I edited the code. Is this what you would like to do? I'm not sure if I understood you question correctly, I tried to guess.

Comment: I am very sorry  i was not very clear but this works and is what I have been looking for. Thank you very much for your patience and help.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you!